# How to fetch only current hour posts?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

How can I fetch the post which is posted only this hour?

Example: It's 9:00 am here I want to show all the post that is posted within 9:00am to 10am and it will check all the hours in same way.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Date Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) is the thing you’re looking for.

So if you want to get posts from given hour, you can construct a query like this:

```
$hour_posts = new WP_Query( array(
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'before' => '2019-05-08 10:00',
    ),
    array(
        'after'  => '2019-05-08 09:00',
    ),
),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
) );
```

And if the day doesn’t matter and you want all posts published within given hour but from all days, then this will come handy:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'hour'      => 9,
            'compare'   => '>=',
        ),
        array(
            'hour'      => 10,
            'compare'   => '<'
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks bro.Actually i m trying to fetch posts based on hours like 1am to 2am  and 2am to 3am and so on

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

```
//set up the round figure of this hour
$timeWithoutA  = date('h:')."00";
$curr_time  = date('h').":00".date('a');

//Add 1 hour to current hour
$timestamp = strtotime($timeWithoutA) + 60*60;
$addedOneHour = date('h:ia', $timestamp);


//Today's date
$this_date = getdate();
$year = $this_date['year'];
$mon = $this_date['mon'];
$day = $this_date['mday'];
$today = $year."-".$mon."-".$day;

//Add them together
$after = $today." ".$curr_time;
$before  = $today." ".$addedOneHour;

$custArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'payment',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'before' => $before,
        ),
        array(
            'after'  => $after,
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query ( $custArgs );


while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
    echo "hello"."<br />";
endwhile;
```